# How to improve poor quality, blurry, Image resolution using CacheMode="BitmapCache"?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a `List` of `BitmapImage`s pre-loaded during the initialization of a `Page`, alls fine.

When I cycle through those images by scrolling and changing the image source a of single Image xaml element, the images flickered. Even though I pre-loaded my `BitmapImage`s

So to solve that I turned on `CacheMode="BitmapCache"` in the `Image` xaml element. After caching all of my images the flickering went away.

But by using `CacheMode="BitmapCache"` I traded off image flickering with poor image quality.

Is anyone aware of this problem? How do you cache all your app images at high resolution so your UI doesn't flicker or suffer from poor image quality?

EDIT: Here is a link of someone on Windows 8 suffering the same problem. https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2014/06/06/The-Danger-of-Setting-CacheMode-to-BitmapCache-on-Windows-8.aspx

This issues is bugging me crazy... How can we make quality UWP apps without image flickering and low quality?

EDIT: So I used higher resolution 4x images with caching, they look much better but for some reason it added 200MB of memory usage which is ridiculous...

So an Image element with large resolutions and image caching and changing the source like 20 times (effectively caching 20 images) creates an additional 200 MB of used memory?

EDIT EDIT: Task manager on my remote machine is reporting 289 MB used, but visual studio is reporting 437 MB used.

Comment: Did you use  `UriSource`  to load the images? Could you please provide any relative code snippet to help us reproduce your issue?

Comment: Visual Studio shows total memory consumption including GPU memory. That's why you see much less memory use in Task Manager. When you caching images you'll get extra 4 bytes per pixel * pixel height * pixel width * images amount. This may be helpful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-animations-and-media

Comment: Can you use win2d?

Comment: Composition API even better https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/06/22/sweet-ui-made-possible-easy-windows-ui-windows-10-creators-update/#8kctd1gT60JrjPFt.97 at the bottom there's an example of parallax photo gallery. They smooth and light